# Value for PRIMARY KEY recognized as NULL (EF6 Code First)

Tags: entity-framework

Well, I have rather odd exception when I try to insert new value. Please, see [attached files](http://rapidshare.com/files/2643355935/Inserting%20Failure%20-%20EF6%20Code%20First.zip) for further investigation.
So, I use:

- SQL Server 2012
- VS 2012 Update 2
- EF6 Alpha 3 Code First

The problem is I'm trying to insert new value into simple table called dbo.Worker2 (see "Worker2 Table" image file) which consists of 2 columns: TableNumber and Name. The TableNumber column is primary key of integer data type (see "Primary Key column properties" image file). I have installed the latest EF6 alpha3 and trying to insert new value (see "VB.NET Code" image file). However, exception is thrown: "Cannot insert NULL the value NULL into column 'TableNumber', table Bonus.dbo.Worker2'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails." (see "VS Exception" image file).

Then I have decided to see what T-SQL query EF sends to SQL Server with SQL Server Profiler and was surprised that no TableNumber was sent by EF (see "Profiler Queries" image file).

Is it bug or I have missed something?

Answer (score 3):

By the looks of it you need to set your Worker2 Primary Key property as non-database generated.

something like:

```
<Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)>
Public Property TableNumber As Integer
```

Comment: Property(x => x.TableNumber).HasColumnName("TableNumber").IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None); using fluent API

Answer (score 0):

I think Primary Key is not set to identity.

Comment: As you can see from "Primary Key column properties" image, it is NOT identity.